# Mysql8.0 upgrade: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, windows

When I try to update mysql using cmd at windows for phpmyadmin error (Your privilege table structure seems to be older than this MySQL version! Please run the mysql_upgrade command(mysql_fix_privilege_tables on older systems) that should be included in your MySQL server distribution to solve this problem!) I have some errors:

"mysql_upgrade: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) while connecting to the MySQL server Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.".

I have password at root user. When I try to use mysqld --skip-grant-tables& it don't work.

Help please.